# Instagram Oauth2 implicit authentication redirect to page unavailable if you introduce bad password

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the oauth2 Instagram implicit flow to do login in Instagram, the base url that I am using is this:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://example.com/oauth_redirect.html&response_type=token

This url show me the Instagram login page, I introduce user and password and if they are correct the API redirects me to the redirect_uri, but when I introduce a bad user or password it redirects me to this unavailable page in Instagram:

https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%MY_CLIENT_ID%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A//example.com/oauth_redirect.html%26response_type%3Dtoken

This is a usual flow where the user doesn't introduce a correct password or email.

How can I resolve it? Is this something related with the configuration.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter exactly the same issue. I've just submit a bug report to the Instagram team, so I hope that would help.

However, I encourage you to do the same to accelerate things, right here: https://help.instagram.com/contact/438525166257277

Comment: Reported the bug as well!  Hopefully they resolve this soon.

Comment: Could you share the link to the bug report? I'd like to subscribe.

Comment: I am facing same issues, have you found any solution for it?

Comment: I can't share the bug report, there is no way to do that. However, Instagram just fixed the bug.