# Bug with Instagram API Login Server-side (Explicit) Flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, instagram, instagram-api

I have a bug with my instagram login Server-side (Explicit) Flow.

I use :
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

But If the user uses a bad password or even if he does not enter the username / password, instagram will display an error page instead of putting username / password invalid. Do you have an idea of ​​the problem? What can I do?
Thank you very much!

[Login insta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqJLI.jpg)

[Error screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaUEG.png)

Comment: Having the same issue. Seems to have started happening in the past 2 weeks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? @hermanschutte

Comment: Not yet, seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972288/instagram-oauth2-implicit-authentication-redirect-to-page-unavailable-if-you-int

Comment: thanks @hermanschutte, please say me if you find a solution